# How to use purrr::possibly() in place of broom::augment()?

Tags: r, purrr

If I run this code:

```
library(tidyverse)
lm(speed ~ dist, data = cars) %>%  broom::augment()
```

I get the following warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: Deprecated: please use `purrr::possibly()` instead 
2: Deprecated: please use `purrr::possibly()` instead 
3: Deprecated: please use `purrr::possibly()` instead 
4: Deprecated: please use `purrr::possibly()` instead 
5: Deprecated: please use `purrr::possibly()` instead
```

But I don't get how I am supposed replace it using `possibly()`, which to me seems to to something different than what I am trying to do.

In fact if I just follow the warnings:

```
> lm(speed ~ dist, data = cars) %>%  purrr::possibly()
Error: Can't convert a list to function
```

Comment: Do you still get the expected results despite the warnings? If so I would say you don't really need to worry about this, warnings are only warnings and do not necessarily point to an error. You could update your installed packages, the warning might go away in a newer version of `broom`.

Comment: https://github.com/tidyverse/broom/issues/228

Comment: To explain why this is happening: `broom::augment` uses some function from `purrr` that is now deprecated, but it's up to the maintainers of `broom` to switch over to the newer `purrr` function, not you.

Comment: @Marius uh ok I should have realized that since it was giving multiple warnings thanks!

Comment: As noted by @CurtF. this is an open Github issue, the developer is aware of it.